# Not even light can escape black hole due to it's pathetic speed or infinite time dilation or extreme curvature of space?

Tags: black-holes

The correct explanation that why black hole is black must be one of the following:

(1) Escape velocity of black hole exceeds speed of light like a pitched baseball can never go into orbit.

(2) From the outside observer perspective, falling clock stops ticking at the event horizon forever due to the intense gravitational pull like why our GPS satellite needs calibration so we don't get lost often.

(3) Light always travel the shortest possible path between two points on a surface, unfortunately for matter that stray close to the event horizon all roads lead to oblivion.

(4) All of the above!

(5) None of the above! so what's the correct answer.

Comment: "pathetic" speed? I'll see you keep up with it... Incidentally - your points are numbered (1), (2), (2), (3), (4). Deliberate?

Comment: Why are those the only possible explanations?  Besides which, who says it's "black" ? You'd have, at the very least, to separate a black hole from the jets belonging to it.

Comment: Black holes aren't black, they are just very, very red.

Comment: Er, what's your actual question?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: these are the explanations I have had at the moment but feel free to donate more :)

Comment: @Floris: I intended to pose it as multiple choice so as that the wrong answers(misconceptions) can be eliminated.

Comment: My point is to bat you usually use different numbers for each of the points. If I said the answer was (2) you still don't know what the answer is...

Comment: @Floris: revised and thanks, it was both a genuine(overlook) and intentional mistake of mine(isn't GR states that gravity is simply the curvature of space-"TIME".)

Comment: @KyleKanos: the problem is causality violation therefore answer can come before question(I'm just kidding!) actually I read a lot of different answers in physic.se and I just need a most accurate one that describe black hole/event horizon.